# Iterating through a Generic Dictionary throws Exception

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
private Dictionary<int, Entity> m_allEntities;
private Dictionary<Entity, List<IComponent>> m_entityComponents;

public Dictionary<int, T> GetComponentType<T>() where T: IComponent
{
    Dictionary<int, T> components = new Dictionary<int, T>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Entity> pair in m_allEntities)
    {
        foreach (T t in m_entityComponents[m_allEntities[pair.Key]])
        {
            components.Add(pair.Key, t);
        }
    }

    return components;
}
```

**m_allEntities** = Dictionary of all Entities with Key: their ID and Value: the Entity object.
**m_entityComponents** = Dictionary of all Entities and their component list with Key: Entity object and Value: it's list of components.

I have several different classes that implement the IComponents interface. What the GetComponentType() function is supposed to do is loop through all entities and create a dictionary of entity IDs and components of a particular type.

For example: if I want to get a list of all Entities that have a Location component then I would use:

```
entityManager.GetComponentType<Location>();
```

The problem that I'm running into is the second loop because it doesn't seem to be filtering through my Dictionary. Instead it tries to cast all components in the dictionary to the Location type which, of course, throws an exception. How can I alter this code so that it does what I want it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) method:

```
foreach (T t in m_entityComponents[m_allEntities[pair.Key]].OfType<T>())
```

to filter elements matching your generic type.

Comment: Just tried this and .OfType<T>() is not a method option for me. Do I need to include an additional using statement for that functionality or something?

Comment: @Kittoes: yes, you need LINQ namespace. Simply add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I thought as much, should've just tried adding LINQ first before asking. I really like this solution because I don't have to cast anything. ChaosPandion's solution above also worked out quite well. Which of the two options is "safer" and is there a performance difference between the two?

Comment: @Kittoes: `OfType<T>` under the hood does the `t is T` comparision (plus few other LINQ related stuff). It's essentially the same. I wouldn't argue on what's more efficient - once compiler does it's job difference will be most likely nonexistent. Go with solution that's explains code's purpose better (as in, is more readable, understandable and so forth).

Answer (score 4):

If your collection has different types you'll need to test for the proper type.

```
public Dictionary<int, T> GetComponentType<T>() where T: IComponent
{
    Dictionary<int, T> components = new Dictionary<int, T>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Entity> pair in m_allEntities)
    {
        foreach (IComponent c in m_entityComponents[m_allEntities[pair.Key]])
        {
            if (c is T)
                components.Add(pair.Key, (T)c);
        }
    }

    return components;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tested this change and it won't even compile. The line that fails is: var t = c as T;. Error: "The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint."

Comment: @Kittoes - I'll ignore the fact that the error is very specific. However if you look at my changes they remove the need for the class constraint.

Comment: Again, thank you very much. That ended up working quite well. jimmy_keen also posted a solution below that I rather liked. Which would you recommend using (since they both do exactly what I need)?

Comment: @Kittoes - Consider that the solution that jimmy_keen provided will save you exactly one line of code. One could however argue that this solution is slightly more efficient as it creates one less iterator.